# Eclipse add custom syntax highlighting based on extension

Tags: eclipse

I've recently started developing with Kivy using Eclipse. I'd like to add some basic syntax coloring for .kv file-types. I've tried googling how to do this but nothing came up. This could also be handy for other filetypes not normally recognized by eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted that eclipse recognize .fo (Apache FOP, a XML FileType) extensions. It means use XML editor to open .fo

I use the next steps in eclipse-kleper:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Content Types
```

Then in fisrt box

```
Text -> XML -> XML Schema File -> Add... -> *.fo (in dialog box)
```

If  Kivy files has a known structure by editor it should work.

I hope it helps you.